# grub2-mkconfig creates grub2-efi.cfg different from the existing one, but why?

Tags: grub2, grub2-mkconfig

On Fedora 29 on a machine with UEFI hardware.

Trying to generate a new `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg`.

Dry run first!

Change nothing in `/etc/default/grub`.

*(Actually wanted to remove `rhgb quiet` from the kernel line, but tit turns out this is done by executing `plymouth-set-default-theme details --rebuild-initrd` instead, see [Why is Grub menu not shown when starting my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer))*

As described in [Create a GRUB 2 configuration](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Create_a_GRUB_2_configuration), a new file can be created by running:

```
grub2-mkconfig
```

The resulting file should go to `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` and is referenced by the symlink:

```
/etc/grub2-efi.cfg --> ../boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

However, running:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o OUT
diff --side-by-side --width=200 /etc/grub2-efi.cfg OUT | less
```

...reveales a certain number of differences between the `OUT` file and the original among which:

`grub2-mkconfig` uses `linuxefi` and `initrdefi` instructions, but `OUT` does not, it uses `linux` and `initrd` instructions. This sounds wrong!

For example:

Sounds correct in `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg` :

```
linuxefi  /vmlinuz-4.19.4-300.fc29.x86_64 ....
initrdefi /initramfs-4.19.4-300.fc29.x86_64.img
```

Sounds wrong in `OUT`:

```
linux     /vmlinuz-4.19.4-300.fc29.x86_64 ....
initrd    /initramfs-4.19.4-300.fc29.x86_64.img
```

What's going on? Is there some option I forgot about? Can I replace the existing `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg`?

Comment: I read somewhere else that this might be related to secure boot and the EFI shim... but I can't figure it out either, and have been wondering about this same issue. Please post an answer if you figure it out.